# How to have the user input taken in a certain part of the display in Python

Tags: python, string, input, display

**I need to know how to have a Python project ask for user input in the middle of the displayed text and not at the end.**

### Example:

```
name=input(("Whats your name? [ ]"))
```

I want the user input to be taken in between the `[ ]`
So, it will have you type your name there.  I tried moving the `()`, so the code would look like this: `name=input("Whats your name?" ("[ ]"))`, but I get this error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

So, if you know why this error is occurring, but don't know how to fix it, I would really appreciate the info about the error and if you know that answer I would really appreciate that two.  Maybe I need to import a module.

Comment: I'm a beginner, don't mock me.

Comment: This is highly nontrivial.

Comment: One thing that's sort of similar to what you're asking is the follows: name="What's your name["+input() +"]", While the name will be between brackets afterwards, it will not be between them during the input.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Interesting answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19580748/1595643

Comment: You would have to use a package that gives you more control over the console, like [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html). This is pretty complicated stuff.

Comment: You could try appending several `"\b"` backspace characters to the end of your prompt string. On many (but perhaps not all) consoles those will make the input cursor move to the left. Your right bracket won't move with the input though, so you'll need to space it out enough to fit the largest name you expect to get. This is probably the only approach short of using curses or another console GUI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght)**

> You could try appending several "\b" backspace characters to the end
>   of your prompt string. On many (but perhaps not all) consoles those
>   will make the input cursor move to the left. Your right bracket won't
>   move with the input though, so you'll need to space it out enough to
>   fit the largest name you expect to get. This is probably the only
>   approach short of using curses or another console GUI library.
>   **That worked perfectly, thank you BlackNight!**